# Find the area of the image of $D (0, 1)$ under tha map $f (z) = z +\frac {z^2}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> Find the area of the image of $D (0, 1)$ under tha map $$f (z) = z +\frac {z^2}{2}$$
> Here's a solution for this:
> $f(w)=f(z)$ if and only if $$(w-z)(1+\frac{w+z}{2})=0$$

so f is injective. Then area of its image is given by $$\int_{\Bbb D}|f'(z)|^2dxdy=\int_{\Bbb D}(1+2Re(z)+ |z|^2)dz$$
$$=\int_{\Bbb D}(1+2x+ x^2+y^2)dxdy$$
$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}(1+2r\cos(\theta)+ r^2)drd\theta$$ $$=\frac{3\pi}{2}$$

Here, I did not understand:

$1.$ What is $f(w)$ and from where did $(w-z)(1+\frac{w+z}{2})=0$ come?

$2.$ How come it is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$? Because after calculation it is $\frac {8\pi}{3}$

Comment: *“What is $f(w)$?”* – You have defined the function as $f (z) = z +\frac {z^2}{2}$. Then $f (w) = w +\frac {w^2}{2}$.

Comment: Oh yeah now I get it. $f(z)-f(w)=0$ and then I just use the equations and factorize them. I am still a novice actually....

Comment: $dxdy=rdrd\theta$ so the integral in polar coordinates is a bit different